# HttpClient postasync request not working with fully qualified hostname, but works using IP address for windows service

Tags: c#, owin, dotnet-httpclient

This is strange, I have C# `HttpClient` `PostAsync` method, it works with IP and without fully qualified hostname however, it does not work with the fully qualified hostname though it works with postman, any idea what is the issue.

Eg; if I enter IP:portname or myvdi:postname it works
but I enter myvdi.swq.tst.local it does not work and it throws error "Method not found"

I repeat no issue with the postman, both cases work in postman.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var requestData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "myusername"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "mypassword")
};

var payload = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

payload.Headers.ContentType =
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") { CharSet = "UTF-8" };

var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://myvdi.swq.tst.local:8096/SourceCtl/source/api/token"), payload).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The URL is windows service and it is configured with OWIN token so it first calls OWIN.

Fiddler

[image]

Comment: What is the exact exception? Can you share with us the StackTrace as well?

Comment: is the dns resolving to the same ip address?

Comment: @PeterCsala Like I said no errors, the response says "404 Not Found"

Comment: 404 means the URL is wrong, not the host. The server got the HTTP request but doesn't recognize `/SourceCtl/source/api/token"`. This has nothing to do with HttpClient

Comment: @DanielA.White It works with postman so is it DNS issue ??

Comment: its possible. node and .net have different dns stacks.

Comment: @DanielA.White how to check that ??

Comment: @Mysterious288 use .net's dns client to see what its resolving

Comment: @Mysterious288 `is it DNS issue?` if it was you wouldn't get a 404 - unless you connect to the *wrong* server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know 404, It works in postman and it works with IP so how it could be wrong url

Comment: @Mysterious288 the server itself says the URL is wrong. What is the *actual* request you used with Postman? How do the two URLs differ? Is the case different perhaps?

Comment: @Mysterious288 use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what the two tools really send. Perhaps the case is different. Perhaps the headers are different. Perhaps the server returns 404 because the *form data* doesn't correspond to an existing record.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for your simplicity "https://myvdi.swq.tst.local:8096/SourceCtl/source/api/token" this does not work, "https://myvdi.8096/SourceCtl/source/api/token" this works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have attached the fiddler snapshot in the question

Comment: The two snapshots show different HOSTs, even though the *relevant* parts are obscured. In the question you wrote that `https://myvdi.swq.tst.local:8096/SourceCtl/source/api/token` doesn't work. The images show a different URL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In the question that is just an example, I can't post actual URL's, this is a serious issue and not a silly mistake where we should concentrate on, I verified everything.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the URLs are different and HttpClient can't do anything about this. The URLs would be served by the same server in only two cases: 1) both your machine and the server are  on a Windows domain named `swq.tst.local`. In that case the domain's DNS would map `myvdi` to `myvdi.swq.tst.local`. 2) you've deployed several services on the same machine and set each site's `HOST` header. You'd have to set *all* possible host headers for that to work. Both `myvdi` *and* `myvdi.swq.tst.local`.

Comment: You'd also have to configure DNS to resolve `myvdi` to the same machine as `myvdi.swq.tst.local`. What do you get when you try to navigate to the two URLs? What happens when you use `nslookup myvdi` and `nslookup myvdi.swq.tst.local`? Have you checked the server's request logs? Do any requests appear?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did nslookup, both point to the same server, in fact both same details

Comment: @Mysterious288 Even I 'm facing the same issue, any solution??

Comment: Any help on this is much appreciated...

Comment: @harshu288 I have posted an answer, do check in case you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have to help myself, this might help someone else, you need to make sure that you register all the endpoints in OWIN, I registered it for a fully qualified name and it worked.

```
    var options = new StartOptions();
    options.Urls.Add($"https://myvdi.swq.tst.local:portno/source/api/token");
        
    WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
```